# How to add/append carousel selection to order preview on actions on google?

Tags: javascript, transactions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to make an actions on google app that will be able to order something I want to be able to add anything I select from the carousel to the order preview. I followed the tutorial provided by actions on google for the "book store" (I'll post the link below) but I can't seem to find any tutorial or documentation on how to add carousel selection to your order preview.

**Edit** To be more specific, this is what I am trying to do:

Users asks:

```
"talk to my app"
>> "Welcome to the app!"
"I would like to order a coffee"
>> Okay, what would you like to order?
   * Carousel appears with different options
*User selects an option and that option gets added to the bill*
 >> Okay, are you ready to check out?
"Yes"
```

and from there, the user **can see what he or she just selected from the carosuel onto the order preview/ bill**.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help!

link [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of code?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample of how to create a browse carousel for Google Assistant, using the Node.js client library:

```
// Create a browse carousel
conv.ask(new BrowseCarousel({
  items: [
    new BrowseCarouselItem({
      title: 'Title of item 1',
      url: googleUrl,
      description: 'Description of item 1',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_AOG,
        alt: a11yText,
      }),
      footer: 'Item 1 footer',
    }),
    new BrowseCarouselItem({
      title: 'Title of item 2',
      url: googleUrl,
      description: 'Description of item 2',
      image: new Image({
        url: IMG_URL_AOG,
        alt: a11yText,
      }),
      footer: 'Item 2 footer',
    }),
  ],
}));
```

More info in the docs here: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel

Comment: So if I add this set of code, not only will I have a carousel but anything I select from this carousel will appear on the order summary before the user finishes the transaction?